# Performance of passing the current thread explicitly vs. implicitly (NULL jthread) to JVMTI

Tags: performance, jvmti

The [JVM Tool Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) has several call-stack related functions (e.g., [`GetStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetStackTrace), [`GetFrameCount`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetFrameCount), or [`GetLocalInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#GetLocalInstance)) which take a `jthread` as argument to determine the affected thread. All of them take a `NULL` argument to mean “the current thread.“

Now suppose I already have a `jthread` referring to the current thread. Which one is then faster?

1. Explicitly passing the current thread as `jthread`
2. Passing `NULL`

Comment: What about running a test and measuring it?

Comment: I did that already using the [DaCapo Benchmark Suite](http://www.dacapobench.org/) frequently used in research: Any difference in performance is lost in the noise introduced by JIT compilation, garbage collection, etc. So I know the performance difference to be small. Still, I was hoping for an answer along the lines of “option 1 is slower than option 2 because an extra lookup is involved internally” to squeeze out the last bit of performance.